# Sending Input from a Form via Ajax Request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

After following the example and answers by the following threads

[jQuery AJAX submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

[submitting a form via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661380/submitting-a-form-via-ajax)

I have built a similar test form to get to learn the ajax request on submit. Your guess was right, it doesn't work for me (no alert popping up).

My testajax.php with the form:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../test.js"></script>

<form name="feedback" id="idForm" action="(myurl)/testajax.php" method="post">

<input id="name" type="text">

<input type="submit" name="feedbacksent" value="Send" />
</p>
</form>
```

My test.js:

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

var url = "(myurl)/testajaxinput.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
```

alert("bla");  // does not work either

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(data)
       {
           alert(data); // show response from the php script.
       }
     });

});
```

My testajaxinput.php that should handle the input:

```
if (isset($_POST['feedbacksent'])){

echo "<h1>".WORKS."</h1>";  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
if (isset($_POST['feedbacksent'])){
    echo "<h1>".WORKS."</h1>";  
    return true;
}
```

Then try your `alert` and also check have you got any error in console.

Comment: Hi, edited the `testajaxinput.php` like you proposed, but still not working :/. Also no errors showing up in the console.

Comment: Put e.preventDefault(); just above the ajax.

Comment: Didn't change anything. I will edit the new code above.

Comment: If I insert `alert("bla");` just in front of the last brackets of the `submit(function(e)` the alert isn't working either.

Comment: In front of what ?

Comment: I edited my `test.js` above in the OP so you can see it.

Comment: Put that alert just above the ajax. See the submit event is working or not ?

Comment: Changes nothing :(.

Comment: I just tested it without the ajax, and it does not work. Since it was not included in the ajax before and didn't work, this is probably not a surprise.